# MYSQL - PHP : getting MySQLi results as array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

This is the update code

But I got the error : FATAL ERROR (Call to undefined method User::fetch_assoc())

this is my method code

```
    public function getAllUsers(User $user) 
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT u.user_id, u.email, u.name, u.phone, u.picture, s.status 
                                      FROM ".$this->table_name." as u, status as s
                                      WHERE u.status_id = s.status_id");
        if($stmt == FALSE)
        {
            die($this->conn->error);
        }
        else 
        {

            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $email, $name, $phone, $picture, $status);

            while($stmt->fetch())
            {
                $user->setUserId($user_id);
                $user->setEmail($email);
                $user->setName($name);
                $user->setPhone($phone);
                $user->setPicture($picture);
                $user->setStatus($status);
            }

            $stmt->close();
            return $user;
        }
    }
```

and this is my code in index.php who called the object method.

```
$app->get('/users', 'authenticate', function() 
{ 
        global $user_id;
        $response = array();


        $user = new User();

        // fetching all users
        $userDB = new UserDb(MySqlDb::getInstance()->connect());
        $result = $userDB->getAllUsers($user);

        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["users"] = array();

        // looping through result and preparing users array
        while ($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {

            $tmp = array();
            $tmp["user_id"] = $user->getUserId();
            $tmp["email"] = $user->getEmail();
            $tmp["name"] = $user->getName();
            $tmp["phone"] = $user->getPhone();
            $tmp["picture"] = $user->getPicture();
            $tmp["status"] = $user->getStatus();
            array_push($response["users"], $tmp);
        }

        echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

please check my foreach, is it wrong ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: try to do   $u['user_id'] = $user->setUserId();

Comment: in `getAllUsers` - I don't think you ever execute the query; You iterate over an empty array, and then return that array. After that you are running `fetch_array()` on that empty array that was returned (which is the error you see).

You should look into the the example of using mysqli [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).

Answer (score 0):

getAllUsers returns an array of Users

so $result is an array of Users, not a database query result as you may expect.

then you call fetch_assoc() on $result, which is an array of users, and as it doesn't have this method, you get `Call to undefined method User::fetch_assoc()`

Comment: I already change the foreach loop with while. But i got that error again.

Comment: why don't you post the exact code you have now, instead of different versions?

Comment: the error is self-explanatory. somewhere you are mixing the variables. you are returning a User array, yet try to call method fetch_assoc on it.